# Bulk download Sci-Hub papers

Tags: data-request, research

I wonder whether it is possible to bulk download all papers stored in [Sci-Hub](http://sci-hub.tw/).

---

I am aware of the questions:

- [Is there a more user-friendly way to download multiple articles from arXiv?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55626/452)
- [Bulk download of arXiv (or other publication data set) with metadata AND citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/59093/452)

but they focus on arXiv.

Comment: A slight correction/addition to philshem's answer. Not a comment due to not having enough reputation. If you need specifically scientific papers, you should use torrents at the following link: http://libgen.io/scimag/repository_torrent_notforall Collection of data accessible through torrents at http://libgen.io/repository_torrent, mentioned by philshem, is focused on books, including textbooks.

Comment: @myrix Thanks, you are correct. As a side note, http://libgen.io/scimag/repository_torrent_notforall need more seeders!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sci-Hub is a paywall-bypassing website that uses "shared" user credentials to provide PDF or HTML scientific papers. The website itself doesn't store any papers. (There are interesting comments on your [same question on another site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/63330).)

But [LibGen (via wayback machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190330215241/https://engineuring.wordpress.com/2019/03/31/sci-hub-and-alexandra-basic-information/) [is said to archive each PDF retrieved by Sci-Hub](https://engineuring.wordpress.com/2019/03/31/sci-hub-and-alexandra-basic-information/).

http://gen.lib.rus.ec has a downloads page - (click the tab to show more options)

- Torrent - books and text books - http://libgen.io/repository_torrent/
- Torrent - scientific papers - http://gen.lib.rus.ec/scimag/repository_torrent/
- Usenet - http://libgen.io/repository_nzb/
- DB dump - http://gen.lib.rus.ec/dbdumps/

[image]

Comment: bonus points for .torrent open data

Comment: yeah - someone can add it to the community wiki http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4088/1511

Comment: done. although i wasn't sure what to add for the torrent size.....the sum of all the torrents in the folder?

Comment: comment placeholder for @myrix:  

A slight correction/addition to philshem's answer. Not a comment due to not having enough reputation.

If you need specifically scientific papers, you should use torrents at the following link:

http://libgen.io/scimag/repository_torrent_notforall

Collection of data accessible through torrents at http://libgen.io/repository_torrent, mentioned by philshem, is focused on books, including textbooks.

Comment: Something everyone should know about downloading LibGen's papers is that they are stored in DjVu files. Which are quite old and aren't as parsable compared to pdf files.

Comment: @albert Thanks, http://libgen.io/scimag/repository_torrent_notforall/ is indeed the way to go for scientific papers. Around 53 million papers, ~18 TB.

Comment: @GabrielFair so far all scientific papers I have seen are in PDF format. Were you talking about the books?

Comment: This all seems to skirt legality...

Comment: @wogsland Legality is based on jurisdiction. Additionally, knowing of somethings existence isn't against any law. It's up to the individual user to understand and follow local laws.

Comment: related hackernews thread: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17115176

Answer (score 5):

The Reddit thread [Can I download all libgen books?](https://www.reddit.com/r/libgen/comments/6f8a57/can_i_download_all_libgen_books/) describes how to download the entire Library Genesis database (~10TB).

Comment: [This is a link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Can you please add the essential information **here**?

Comment: While the answer is updated for it, a mirror to the reddit post: http://web.archive.org/web/20200419171525/https://www.reddit.com/r/libgen/comments/6f8a57/can_i_download_all_libgen_books/

Answer (score 0):

Another resource which is a legal alternative to sci-hub.tw is **[Unpaywall](https://unpaywall.org/)**.

> We harvest content directly from over 50,000 journals and open-access repositories from all over the world. We also use great open data from PubMed Central, the DOAJ, Crossref (particulary their license info), and DataCite.

---

- [Rest API](https://unpaywall.org/products/api): takes a DOI and returns JSON data with URLs to paper PDF

Example: https://api.unpaywall.org/v2/10.1038/nature12373?email=YOUR_EMAIL

- [Simple query tool](https://unpaywall.org/products/simple-query-tool)
- [Browser extension](https://unpaywall.org/products/extension)

---

- [Database snapshot](https://unpaywall.org/products/snapshot):

> To complete the download of the full dataset, please fill out [this form](https://goo.gl/forms/AZqaqKEzMcjLGdTT2), which helps us report usage back to our funders, and we'll immediately provide you with a download link.